# Within same regex expression , performing multiple regex operations

Tags: regex, nested

How can i perform a new regex operation to a regex group , all within same regex expression ?
"Nested Regex Operations maybe?"

Greetings , i kind of understand how regex works but i havent been able to perform this operation yet using regex , which i can do with c# combined with regex.

As in example.

"The quick 1234brown fox jumps over the lazy 1234dog"

The regex   (quick 1234brown fox jumps over the lazy)
yields to "quick 1234brown fox jumps over the lazy"

And im looking for that "1234" . From that first result.
Like
Using regex (1234)  to "quick 1234brown fox jumps over the lazy"
Which will return "1234".

---

In c# im able to make this work by using regex multiple times.

```
    string test_string = "The quick 1234brown fox jumps over the lazy 1234dog";
    string clipped_text = "";
    string end_result = "";

    var match = Regex.Match(test_string, "quick 1234brown fox jumps over the lazy", RegexOptions.Singleline);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        clipped_text = match.Value;

        match = Regex.Match(clipped_text, "1234", RegexOptions.Singleline);
        if (match.Success)
            end_result = match.Value;
    }
```

---

I want to do the same thing with just one regex expression.
Of course , the example is very simple and can be done with /w .* [] etc, other basic regex rules.
But i had to simplify my example down to this level , in order to get a clear answer. 
Assuming the above c# example regexes itself again , i face situations where i need to regex the result multiple times more .
Obviously this comes from being a c# programmer and im not very familiar with regex yet but im learning.
In my confusion , i got stuck and currently i cant go any further with tutorials without frying my brain.
So any help about how to solve this in a nested regexes way will be greatly appreciated, thank you very much !

Comment: I am not sure what you are specifically trying to achieve? Are you looking for a number that repeats further in the same string? Requiring a *back-reference*?

Answer (score 0):

From your description it sounds like you need to use the backreference construct

[Backreference Construct :MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwdfzxy.aspx)

There are examples in the linked page. Using this you can refer to repeated occurrences of a substring within a string.